# Error with 'getProfilePicture'

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, picturebox, user-profile, xcode6.1

I have a profile view controller where the user can set or change his or her profile picture but am getting constant errors that do not make sense to me.

```
-(void)getProfilePicture
{
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    NSLog(@"file--%@",[user objectForKey:PF_USER_PICTURE]);

    userName = user[PF_USER_USERNAME];
    status = user[PF_USER_STATUS];

    if ([user objectForKey:PF_USER_PICTURE]) {
        [imageUser setFile:[user objectForKey:PF_USER_PICTURE]];
        [imageUser loadInBackground];
    }
    else{
        imageUser.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_profile@2x.png"];
    }


//    fieldName.text = user[PF_USER_FULLNAME];
}

#pragma mark - UIActionSheetDelegate
```

I receive the following errors portrayed in my ProfileViewController.m (I can provide/add .h if needed):

**"No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'setFile:'**

**"No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'loadInBackground'**

Any help would be much appreciated or any supporting code thats needed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what it does for you:

```
-(void)getProfilePicture
{
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    NSLog(@"file--%@",[user objectForKey:PF_USER_PICTURE]);

    userName = user[PF_USER_USERNAME];
    status = user[PF_USER_STATUS];

    if ([user objectForKey:PF_USER_PICTURE]) {
        userImage.file = [user objectForKey:PF_USER_PICTURE];
        [userImage loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                imageUser.image = image;
                [imageUser setNeedsDisplay];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
        }];
    }
    else{
        imageUser.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_profile@2x.png"];
    }


//    fieldName.text = user[PF_USER_FULLNAME];
}

#pragma mark - UIActionSheetDelegate
```

This is assuming your `userImage` is a `PFImageView` and `[user objectForKey:PF_USER_PICTURE]` is a `PFFile`.

**EDIT**

Actually, looking at your error it seems that `userImage` is just a `UIImageView` not a `PFImageView`, which might be the source of all your problems. Try making the `userImage` a `PFImageView`

Comment: Thank you but the last part I just wanted more clalification, which do I make PFImageView from which term? "userImage"?

Comment: Yeah actually in the sense of clarification how exactly do I make the userImage a PFImageView? I am no expert coder so step by step would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing that `userImage` is a property. So make your `@property` declaration `@property PFImageView *userImAage;`

Comment: So I paste your corrected code and change the property that is within the same .m?

Comment: You might not even need to use the code I posted. First just try changing the property in the .m file

Comment: No luck, only created more errors, I think you might want to see my entire .m, is there a convenient way I can send for you to take a look?

Comment: You can send it to me via email and I will take a look at it: robbiefjohnson@gmail.com

Comment: Greatly appreciate it.